# How to replace a fragment using NavController.navigate instead of adding it on top

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I'm using the "new" Android Jetpack navigation, instead of relying on FragmentManager. I've got a simple main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/root"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNav">

        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_app" />

    </FrameLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/root"/>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And two additional layouts: "Splashscreen" with a TextView, "Login" with a button. The splashscreen fragment is used as starting point, and has a listener defined as follows:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        textView.setOnClickListener{
            findNavController(nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.action_splashScreenFragment_to_loginFragment)
        }
    }
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px3a0.jpg)

Instead of replacing TextView fragment with Button fragment, the Button fragment is stacked on top.

I've only encountered workarounds such as setting a background color, and clickable parameter, which I consider to be more of a hack, as I believe that the behaviour is exactly the same, but the fragment below is simply hidden. How to properly switch fragments using the NavController?

Comment: Navigation never allows two Fragments to overlap. Please include your Activity code and where the TextView fragment and Button Fragment are being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue seems to have occured because of these two lines:

```
val host = NavHostFragment.create(R.navigation.navigation_register_login)
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,host).setPrimaryNavigationFragment(host).commit()
```

I guess they shouldn't be called, and all basic requirements are fulfilled by this line in layout:

```
android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
```

Comment: Wouldn't this ruin how it thinks the state is? What if I always want it to just replace? Can I perhaps use defaultNavHost=false ? I've noticed that if I do this, onDestroy isn't called on previous fragments when using navigate . Here’s a sample code:
https://gofile.io/?c=Sv5DLb

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `popUpTo` and `popUpToInclusive` to clear the backstack.
Check the [Android Developers docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#pop)

Comment: I thought that popUpTo (+ inclusive) refers to how many fragments pop off the stack? That is, having a stack:
A -> B -> C -> D
And calling navigate(action_D_to_E) with popupTo(A) would leave me with stack:
A -> E ? That is after executing 'back' two times i would exit the app? It doesn't seem to have anything in common with my issue. Pleas check the attached screen.

Comment: yep, sorry, missed the screenshot. I would make `Fragments` background opaque in your case.

Comment: @budgie Your answer is wrong and your comment is also wrong as making background opaque is not always possible