# How to go from one fragment to another fragment by click on menu item

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

I want to move from the fragment I am in by the add (+) item to the add fragment.
How do I switch between fragments in the menu?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaULc.png)

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.student_list_menu,menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.addStudentFragment){
        Log.d("TAG","ADD...");
        return true;
    }else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

[Menu view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaULc.png)

Comment: Normally you use [`FragmentTransaction`](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions) .. in case If you are using `NavigationGraph` then its bit different .

Comment: Something like `NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(R.id.action_fragment` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55893920/how-to-replace-a-fragment-using-navcontroller-navigate-instead-of-adding-it-on-t

Comment: I'm using NavigationGraph, how can I do that with NavigationGraph?

Answer (score 0):

just use navigation component and navigate

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.student_list_menu,menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.addStudentFragment){
        Log.d("TAG","ADD...");
findNavController(HERE YOUR FRAGMENT ID YOU WANT TO NAVIGATE)
        return true;
    }else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```